# How can I add a header to a form that has already been defined in Odoo?

Tags: odoo

Is it possible to inherit a form view and add a header to it? I've tried:

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
  <xpath expr="//form" position="before">
    <header>
      <h1>hi</h1>
    </header>
  </xpath>
</field>
```

and

```
<form position="inside">
    <header>
        <h1>hi</h1>
    </header>
</form>
```

What can I do? I want to add buttons to the form in a nice manner without needing to redefine the whole form.

Answer (score 3):

```
<xpath expr="/form/*" position="before">
    <header>
        <h1>hi</h1>
    </header>
</xpath>
```

Note that this requires for the parent form to not be empty.

Answer (score 1):

This will take the current header and then replace it by the header you'll define here.

```
<xpath expr="//form/header" position="replace">
    <header>
        <h1>hi</h1>
    </header>
</xpath>
```